System.ArgumentOutOfRangeExcepion when Insert(0, object) in an ObservableCollection<T>
I have a class name as : "public class NotesGroup<Note> : ObservableCollection<Note>"
I receive the following :
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index')'
when I use ObservableCollection.Insert(0, NotesGroup<Note`> g)
I cannot find my error.
The call stack shows :
0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF in Android.Runtime.RuntimeNativeMethods.monodroid_debugger_unhandled_exception C#
0x1A in Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper._unhandled_exception at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:12,5 C#
0x20 in Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPII_V at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:155,26 C#
0x8 in System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRange_IndexMustBeLessException    C#
0x9 in System.Collections.Generic.List.get_Item C#
0x2 in System.Collections.Generic.List.System.Collections.IList.get_Item    C#
This arrives when I use Mopups.
Can anyone have the same problem ?
and perhaps the solution ?
Thank you.
